# Map from Compactification to Original Space

Tags: general-topology, compactification

If one has a map $f$ from a topological space $X$ to another space $Y$ and then one takes the compactification of $Y$ (for example, if $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$ the compactification is constructed by taking the point at infinity), does $f^{-1} $ take a point in the compactification of $Y$ back to a point in the compactification of $X$?

Comment: Most maps don't have inverses, and even if $f^{-1}: Y \to X$ exists, there's no guarantee that we can extend it to $Y^*$ and maintain continuity.

Comment: Which compactification? There are infinitely many possible compactifications. What you describe for $\Bbb R^n$ is not called "the compactification", but *the one-point compactification*, because it is accomplished by adding a single point to $\Bbb R^n$.